# building table-less div on div block

Tags: css, html

well its really a basic question! I want to build a div block that contains other divs that may overflow on another div! This is an example picture:

[image]

Well i used position:relative with top and left, but it looks awkward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your container div is set to "Position:relative;" and its children divs set to "position:absolute;". That way all the children divs will take the div with the relative positioning as a point of reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. It is another way of doing the same with more functionality. Have a look at [jQuery masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It may work for you. Else [Ordered masonry](https://github.com/tasuk/masonry-ordered).